# PHP is $_SESSION enough to secure the web page?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am running a simple service where users have to login to be able to operate special functonalities.

My MySQL database stores the `username`, `password` and `user_id`.

When user wants to login, they must provide their username and password which are posted to profile.php.

The profile.php does a simple check:

```
// Sanity Check
if(empty($_POST['smart_email'])|| empty($_POST['smart_password']))
{

    echo 'Sorry, wrong login/passwd';
    exit;
}
else
{
    //
    $smart_email = $_POST['smart_email'];
    $smart_password=$_POST['smart_password'];

    // Check if registerd and password matches
    if(DB_IsAuthorized($smart_email, $smart_password) == true)
    {
        // Obtain proper UserID from the database
        $UserID             = DB_GetId($smart_email);

        // set the session user_id variable
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $UserID;


        //
        // Display the User profile page
        //
    }

}
```

From that moment, every single page that is user-related has a check for `user_id` set in `$_SESSION` to find out if this user was logged in and is authorized.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id']>0) 
{ 
    // USER IS LOGGED IN 
}
```

The question is: Is this `$_SESSION['user_id']` check enough to secure the pages from NON LOGGED IN USERS ?

Comment: Actually, yes, it's enought. But without any other measure your visitors is valnurable to most attack on their account. 
I can propose you to use a framework and aquire ssl sertificate to make https. Don't disparage it! People who creates framework has a lot of experience!
By the way - i've like Yii, it's rather simple :)

Comment: When it comes to securing pages on your site, I don't think there's ever enough that can be done. However, I think that generally speaking a simple `$_SESSION` check can be enough.

Comment: Maybe I was off topic at first here. Are you asking if using the `$_SESSION` will allow you to block content from not logged in users; or how secure the `$_SESSION` is and entering areas of brute force attacks, hijacking, etc.

Comment: In and of itself it's okay - but as chris85 said you'd want to check and make sure people weren't using it to brute force user accounts. Whenever I log a user in I record the time and IP. Every time I check my session vars after that, I also check that there has not been a more recent login on that account, and that the IP hasn't changed. If it has, typically I terminate both sessions and force the user to login again. This puts up an additional barrier since an attacker wouldn't be able to take action by hijacking an existing session - they would need to know the username and pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is too broad but simple answer is **no**.

Firstly, you will need https to make sure you protect users from hackers by using firewalls and other required security tools.

Secondly, you need to use htaccess to change extensions, say show user .html instead of .php

Thirdly, Sessions can be hijacked easy by hackers. So always try to store encrypted session values instead of plain text.

There are a lot more issues to take care of but its too complex and broad.

Comment: 1) - this is obvious.
2) Why do i show .html instead of .php ? what's the point?
3) makes sense

the **no** answer is kind of strange, every single page says use $_SESSION in PHP - i assume that getting these 3 points done it is safe to use $_SESSION checks then.

Comment: As to point 2 `security by obscurity is one of the weakest forms of security`. -http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php

Comment: Changing php to html has proven to reduce hackers from attacking. These points are enough for $_SESSION but not for other attacks. And the answer no, was to show that the code is not well written. It needs encryption and is also prone to simple sql injection.

Comment: @Manikiran this is interesting, where is the SQL injection possible here? thanks for your input into this.

Comment: @PeeS I assumed that your `DB_IsAuthorized()` function does not encrypt or hash the values before comparing to values in DB.

Comment: If a hacker has access to the session data stored on the server then encrypting it there wont increase security because then he most likleky will also has acesse to the script that does en-/decrypting.

Comment: Where has changing the extension to `html` ever prevented an attack?

Comment: @PeeS You haven't proved any of your database interactions so telling if you are or aren't open to SQL injections is not possible.

Comment: @Chris85 - that's why i  asked Manikiran for reply as there is no code for SQL at all. We are talking about the pages that are secured against 'not logged in' users by using $_SESSION as check

Comment: @chris85 I agree that changing the extension is the weakest form of security but the second line on the same manual page says *"But in some cases, every little bit of extra security is desirable."*.

Comment: @PeeS sql injections are caused mostly by non logged in users only :P

Comment: Okay but i didn't want to touch SQL injection in this post :) i wanted to ensure that pages checked against $_SESSION are enough to check if user IS logged in or not :)

I am sure that SSL + MySQL PDO and a lot more is needed to secure a page from SQL injection, but this is not the case here :)

Comment: @PeeS Yes everything in your code is fine, except it would be great to encrypt the values. It does not just help you from hackers getting access but also prevents by confusing the hackers. So bottom line is, you encrypt the values, you are good to go with sessions.

Comment: @Manikiran thanks mate, what values should i encrypt here, the POST values which user types in as text (where e-mail is stored as text and password is md5 encrypted in DB?) or the $_SESSION['user_id'] value (which is obviously an INTEGER) ?

Comment: @PeeS Encrypt everything and with a unique algorithm, which supports decryption. But make sure you don't mess up saving large values in Database, which is waste of time and memory. Think logical and select those values you think really need encryption. Don't forget to select my answer if it has helped you (Not great but still gave you (and me too) some knowledge).

Comment: @Manikiran, thanks - will have to dig deeper to get this done if i want to public the page then. It was a good lesson !

Comment: Better technique is to store password hashes rather than the decryptable version such as MD5. Hashes are the only real secure and acceptable way of storing passwords. Furthermore, your session should store an unique value every time the user logs in. This can be done using the user record identifier and the timestamp of the login, encrypted of course. Upon expiration of the session, the timestamp must also expire. This way even intrusion into your sessions or db will result in unusable data.